# how to read the csv file from Java and add the integers in each row (convert string to int)

Tags: java, csv

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("example.csv")); 
             Scanner scanSecond = null; 
             while(scan.hasNextLine()) { 
                 String line = scan.nextLine();  
                 scanSecond = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(","); 
                 int sum =0; 
                 while(scanSecond.hasNextInt()) {
                     sum +=scanSecond.nextInt();
                 }       
                 System.out.println(line+"sum:"+sum); 
                 scanSecond.close();
             }
```

input example)
read from csv file :

Apple,A,30,Banna,B,200
PinApple,C,40,berry,D,90
...

after this part :

```
scanSecond = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(",");
```

Apple A 30 Banna  B 200
PinApple C 40  berry D 90
....

and next ,here this part doesn't work :

```
                 String line = scan.nextLine();  
                 scanSecond = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(","); 
                 int sum =0; 
                 while(scanSecond.hasNextInt()) {
                     sum +=scanSecond.nextInt();
                 }
```

What I've found is, it's treated as a string, so it's doesn't work by nextInt.
so i changed it like this :

```
 while(scanSecond.hasNext()) {  //check it work  
                      // System.out.print(scanSecond.next()+" "); 
              }
```

what i want is make sum of number each row.
but i couldn't change it string to int . how to do it?

Comment: hasNextInt() will continue to fail if you don't get the next token. So you have to check if the next token is an int, if it is not you have to get it, and ignore, so check again if the next is an int. The second while condition is correct, you just need an if in your while body, to consume the tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mario mentioned in the comment to your question you need to check if the next item in your line between the delimiters is an `int`.

Example Code:

```
  String line = scan.nextLine();
  scanSecond = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(",");

  int sum = 0;

  while (scanSecond.hasNext()) {
    if(scanSecond.hasNextInt()) {
      sum += scanSecond.nextInt();
    } else {
      scanSecond.next();
    }
  }
```